# Implement Boruvka's algorithm in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to do Boruvka algorithm in coq, but I stuck in the last part.
Below is my code:

```
From LF Require Export Lists.
From LF Require Export Basics.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Definition vertics := list(nat).
Definition edges := list(nat*nat*nat).
Definition Graph := (vertics, edges).


(*takes in a list of edges from the graph and returns the edge with the smallest weight.*)
Fixpoint minEdge (l: edges)(m: nat*nat*nat): nat*nat*nat :=
match l with
  | nil => m
  | cons h t => match h, m with
                | (a,b,w), (a2,b2,m) => if (leb w m) 
                 then (minEdge t (a,b,w))
                 else (minEdge t (a2,b2,m))
                end
  end.

(*takes in a node and check whether the node has been visited in the new graph*)
Fixpoint first_visit(v: vertics) (node: nat): bool:=
match v with
  | nil =>true
  | cons h t => if (eqb h node)
           then false
           else first_visit t node
end.

(*takes in a node that is going to be removed and return the updated list*)
Fixpoint remove_node (node : nat) (vertics : list nat) : list nat :=
match vertics with
  | nil => nil
  | y::tl => if (eqb node y) 
             then (remove_node node tl)
             else y::(remove_node node tl)
    end.

(*takes in a node that has been visited and then remove it from the graph*)
Definition remove_visitied_node (l: vertics)(m: nat*nat*nat): vertics :=
match m with
  | (a,b,w) => (remove_node a (remove_node b l))
end. 

Notation "x :: l" := (cons x l)
                     (at level 60, right associativity).
Notation "[ ]" := nil.
Notation "[ x ; .. ; y ]" := (cons x .. (cons y nil) ..).
Check [1;2].

(*takes in a node and adds the node to the minimum spanning tree.*)
Definition add_node (v:list nat) (m: nat*nat*nat): vertics :=
match v, m with
  | [], (a,b,w) => [a; b]
  | e, (a,b,w) =>  if ((first_visit e a) && (first_visit e b))
                   then e++[a;b]
                   else if (first_visit v a)
                        then e++[a]
                        else if(first_visit v b)
                        then e++[b]
                        else v

end.

(*takes in an edge and adds the edge to the minimum spanning tree.*)
Definition add_edges (e: list (nat*nat*nat)) (m: nat*nat*nat): edges :=
  e++[m].

(*takes in an edge and removes it from the graph.*)
Fixpoint remove_edge (e: edges) (m: nat*nat*nat) : edges :=
match e with
  | nil => nil
  | h::t => match h,m with
            | (a1,b1,w1), (a2,b2,w2) => if ((eqb a1 a2) && (eqb b1 b2) && (eqb w1 w2))
                                        then t
                                        else h::(remove_edge t m)
            end
end.

(* function returns the first edge from the list*)
Definition first_edge (e: edges) : (nat*nat*nat) :=
match e with
  | [] => (0,0,100)
  | hv::tv => hv
end.

(* boruvka construct a new graph with adding the smallest edge to the new graph until all nodes are visited*)
Fixpoint boruvka (min_tree: edges*vertics) (e: edges) (v: vertics): edges*vertics :=
match v with
  | [] => min_tree
  | x => (boruvka (add_edges e (minEdge e (first_edge e)),(add_node v (minEdge e (first_edge e))))
                  (remove_edge e (minEdge e (first_edge e)))
                  (remove_visitied_node x (minEdge e (first_edge e))))
end.
```

The last definition pops an error msg like this: Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix.
Anyone know how can I fix this? I've checked the error msg, it seems like coq cannot combine so many functions in one function.  IDK how can I implement Boruvka without combining all these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Fixpoint's automatic termination check to work, any recursive call must be called with a structurally smaller argument.
For example, when you are computing over a tree, you can recurse over the subtrees.

In your case you are considering different cases of `v` but then you send `v` as an argument to your recursive function, so the automatic checker can't know if you are perhaps creating an infinite loop.

To solve that, you will have to provide some kind of proof that *something* is decreasing - it could be the height of the tree, the number of parts in edges and vertices, etc., and use that proof as the decreasing argument.

If you use `Require Import Program.` and `Program Fixpoint ...` you get some more tools to prove that your program really recurses.

In your case, it looks like the length of the list `vertices` should be decreasing, so add the annotation `{measure (length v)}`.

```
Require Import Program.
Program Fixpoint boruvka (min_tree: edges*vertics) 
      (e: edges) (v: vertics) {measure (length v)}: edges*vertics := 
   ...
End.

Next Obligation.
```

Then you are thrown into proof mode and need to prove that

```
length (remove_visitied_node v (minEdge e (first_edge e))) <
length v
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove that `remove_visitied_node` reduces the length of the list x - which should be trivial. Then you can use `length x` as reducing measure of the Fixpoint.

See in the manual:(https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/inductive.html#grammar-token-fixannot) and (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/program.html#program-fixpoint)