# Is there anyway I can output all the shortest path in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am trying to write a function that can find all the shortest paths for different vertices. However, my function can only find the shortest path of two vertices. Below is my code:

```
From LF Require Export Lists.
From LF Require Export Basics.
Require Import Program.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition vertics := list(nat).
Definition edges := list(nat*nat*nat).

Definition myEdges : edges := [(1,2,2);(1,3,1);(1,4,5);(2,3,4);(2,4,2);(3,4,2)].

Fixpoint minEdge (l: edges)(m: nat*nat*nat): nat*nat*nat :=
match l with
  | nil => m
  | cons h t => match h, m with
                | (a,b,w), (a2,b2,m) => if (leb w m) 
                 then (minEdge t (a,b,w))
                 else (minEdge t (a2,b2,m))
                end
  end.
```

The edges (nat*nat*nat) represents (vertice1,vertice2,distance between 2 vertices).

So I was expecting the function will start from vertice1, find the paths of (1,3,1),(3,4,2),(4,2,2),(2,1,2) like the pic shown below. (shortest path for the whole graph)
[image: graph]

However, my function can only output (1,3,1).
Can anyone help me with this? How can I fix the function?

Comment: Are you asking about the programming problem in general, or about how to write it in Coq?  If you can write it in any (strict) functional programming language, then you can easily write it in Coq.  The problem is just to show that it it terminates. Do you have a specific algorithm in mind?

Comment: @larsr I do. I wanna implement the Boruvka algorithm. And I split all the steps to different functions as this post shown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67069024/implement-boruvkas-algorithm-in-coq

Comment: @larsr I read the answers and try to prove the length of vertices is reducing but I got stuck... and I am wondering if there is a way that I can simply get the answer I want in just one function.. not bunches of functions so that I won't get stuck in the final step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a naive algorithm

```
Require Import Program.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

(* Vertices : we use nat *)
Definition vertex := nat.
Definition vertices := list vertex.

(* Weight : we use nat *)
Definition weight := nat.

(* Edge : 2 vertices + weight *)
Definition edge := (vertex * vertex * weight)%type.
Definition edges := list edge.

(* Path : 2 vertices + weight + intermediate vertices *)
Definition path := (vertex * vertex * weight * vertices)%type.
Definition paths := list path.

Definition leb := Nat.leb.
Definition eqb a b := (leb a b && leb b a)%bool.

(* The example *)
Definition myEdges : edges := 
  [(1, 2, 2); (1, 3, 1); (1, 4, 5);
   (2, 3, 4) ; (2, 4, 2); (3, 4, 2)].
Definition myVertics := [1; 2; 3; 4].

(* edgesToPaths *)

Fixpoint edgesToPaths (l: edges) : paths :=
match l with
  | nil => nil
  | cons h t => match h with
                | (a, b, w) => (a, b, w, []) :: edgesToPaths t 
                end
  end.

Definition myPaths := edgesToPaths myEdges.

Compute myPaths.

(* Add a path in a list of paths keeping only the shortest *)
Fixpoint addPath1 (p : path) (l : paths) : paths :=
match l with
  | nil => cons p nil
  | cons h t => match h, p with
                | (a1, b1, w1, _), (a2, b2, w2, _) => 
                if (eqb a1 a2 && eqb b1 b2)%bool then
                  if (leb w1 w2)%bool then l else p :: t
                else if (eqb a1 b2 && eqb b1 a2)%bool then
                  if (leb w1 w2)%bool then l else p :: t
                else h :: addPath1 p t
                end
  end.

Definition addPath p ls := 
  match p with
  | (a, b, w, l) => if (eqb a b) then ls
                    else if (leb a b) then addPath1 p ls
                    else addPath1 (b, a, w, rev l) ls
  end.


(* Test *)

(* No progress *)
Compute addPath (1, 4, 10, []) myPaths.

(* Progress *)
Compute addPath (1, 4, 2, []) myPaths.

(* Reflexive *)
Compute addPath (1, 1, 2, []) myPaths.

(* extend  *)
Fixpoint extendPaths (p : path) (l: paths) : paths :=
match l with
  | nil => nil
  | cons h t => match p, h with
                | (a1, b1, w1, l1), (a2, b2, w2, l2) =>
                      let t1 := addPath h (extendPaths p t) in
                      if (eqb b1 a2) then
                        addPath (a1, b2, w1 + w2, l1 ++ b1 :: l2) t1
                      else if (eqb b1 b2) then
                        addPath (a1, a2, w1 + w2, l1 ++ b1 :: rev l2) t1
                      else if (eqb a1 a2) then
                        addPath (b1, b2, w1 + w2, rev l1 ++ a1 :: l2) t1
                      else if (eqb a1 b2) then
                        addPath (b1, a2, w1 + w2, rev l1 ++ a1 :: rev l2) t1
                      else t1
               end
end.

(* Test *)

Compute extendPaths (1, 2, 2, []) myPaths.

(* Use the path in l1 to extend the path in l2 *)
Fixpoint listExtendPaths (l1 l2 : paths) : paths :=
match l1 with
  | nil => l2
  | cons h t => listExtendPaths t (extendPaths h l2)
  end.


(* Test *)

Compute listExtendPaths myPaths myPaths.

(* To get the minimal the paths we iter the listExtendPath enough time
   (a minimal path has no repetition of vertices)   *)
Fixpoint iter n l :=
match n with 
  0 => l 
|
  S n1 => iter n1 (listExtendPaths l l)
end.

Definition getMinPaths (vs : vertices) (es : edges) := 
    iter (length vs) (edgesToPaths es).

Compute myPaths.
Compute getMinPaths myVertics myEdges.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function minEdge is not building a path. It just finds the edge of minimum weight in the list of edges.

Comment: Hi Lolo, could you tell me how can I improve the function for building the shortest path?

Comment: @domino Checkout [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

@domino If you want a naive algorithm:

- write a function `f` that given a `k` computes all the paths of length `k` and their weight
- if your graph has `n` nodes, get the minimum of `f 1`, `f 2`, ... `f n`

If you want an effective algorithm, you need to look at the literature